# Is it sufficient to learn only React Native for building iOS and Android apps?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I recently learnt ReactJS and am getting adept at building web apps with it. I want to now build mobile apps (Android and iOS) using the new-found knowledge.

Is it sufficient for me to learn React Native to do that? And not have to learn Swift (iOS) and Java (Android). It seems logical that React-Native is the path of least resistance to get mobile apps going since I have no prior experience with mobile app programming.

Am I giving up anything by not using the native / traditional stacks for iOS and Android?

Thanks,
- deepak

Comment: **Knowing** is **ALWAYS** better than **not knowing**. Can you get away with it most of the time ? Probably, depends on what you are doing..As you will soon find out this is ***"primarily opinion-based "*** and will close within seconds...

Answer (score 2):

One must understand why React Native is a thing in the scene. You can start development for mobile with your existing knowledge. You will proceed with the least amount of friction. Actually one who has been doing React for a while can start right away.

But there are downsides to it too as every technology has.
You might encounter situations(less likely) in future where you will want to use platform APIs. Developers who do not have knowledge of Objective-C or Swift and core libraries cannot start building native modules on their own.

Actually a technology must be selected on the basis of the team, time constraints and app requirements.
Do not just limit yourself to a particular technology. And as a developer your full time job should be to learn new technologies. 
Do not get afraid of missing out on something.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have been developing iOS and Android apps natively by Obj-C, Swift and Java for last 8 years. Recently, a few months ago, I started, learning React Native to develop some cross-platform apps.

Honestly speaking, it doesn't matter if you never develop iOS or Android app natively, but if you have previous experience then working for mobile devices you will get some advantages.

Using react native, you can develop feature riched application without issue and I guess in rare cases you may need to develop some native component and glue it with react native.

Just learn react native with expo, and start building, over time you will get the whole picture of mobile apps development. You no need to learn native way to develop apps.